# JavaScript in Vue Component, set Data property in object 1 tp data in object 2 if Key matches

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I think I'm close to a solution but I need some help,

I have a form object I want to update where key's match to an imported object.

form.title would be set to the value in article.title.

I have done the following, but am struggling how to set this.form[key][value] to this.article[articleKey][articleValue].

```
             Object.entries(this.form).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                Object.entries(this.article).forEach(([articleKey, articleValue]) => {
                    if ([articleKey][0] === [key][0]){
                         //[value] = [articleValue];
                         //this.form[key][value]=this.article[articleKey][articleValue]
                    }
                });
```

Any help would be appreciated, i'm new to javascript. I can't clone the object as i only want to update the data properties in form and bring across all the data in article object.

Response to comment - example of form

```
form: new Form({
                title: '',
                description: '',
                earliest_date:'',
                latest_date:'',
                image_file_names:[]
    })
```

Article Example

```
        {"id":21,
        "owner_id":1,
        "title":"test1",
        "description":"Test It",
        "earliest_date":"2020-06-01",
        "latest_date":"2020-06-06",
        "image_file_names":"[\"1593530083background.jpg\", 
         \"159353008520190713_085629.jpg\"]",
         "physical_description":"Test 1"}
```

Comment: can you share the form and article data and its structure?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be working, it felt wrong setting value to the key but its not doing that, it is setting value of that key.

```
            Object.entries(this.form).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                Object.entries(this.article).forEach(([articleKey, articleValue]) => {
                    if ([articleKey][0] === [key][0]){
                        this.form[key] = [articleValue];
                    }
                });
            });
```